# How to print directly from a button in android app without print dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, printing

I would like to print an image from my android application (printer:  with wifi direct). I tried the Google API with the android.support.v4.print.PrintHelper class. It work but i have no way to bypass the system dialog. I would like the the application do not interact with the system UI.

user just print the button and start printing on the default connect printer.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Android has no support for this. You would have to do your own printing, bypassing Android's print framework.

Comment: @CommonsWare what own printing , can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You would need to talk to the printer through its own protocol (Bluetooth, WiFI, whatever) and send it data in its own print language (Postscript, PCL, whatever).

Comment: @CommonsWare Cant see any library available for that

Comment: I doubt that there is much available for it. If you are targeting a single printer with a single protocol, it might not be too bad. Or, if you are creating your own Android firmware and do not need the dialog, you might be able to modify the AOSP to support your use case. But if you are trying to to support arbitrary printers with arbitrary protocols from an app running on arbitrary devices... you probably do not have enough engineering staff to do that.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes , i am targeting the single printer..